# JSONObject.getJSONArray() does not recognize an Array

Tags: java, json

Why `JSONObject.getJSONArray()` does not recognize the array? Does being empty has influence?

Here you have the Java code:

```
String inputJSON = "{'links':'[]','format':'csv'}";
JSONObject jsonInput = null;
try {
    jsonInput = new JSONObject(inputJSON);
    String formatExport = jsonInput.getString("format");
    JSONArray jsonLinks = jsonInput.getJSONArray("links");
}
```

Got the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: JSONObject["links"] is not a JSONArray.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exception explanation:**

The `'links':'[]'` property **is a String** on your code. Anything between quotes, `'wh4t3v3r'`, will be treated as a String, and you are treating to read links as a `JSONArray`, and it is not.

**Solutions**:

1. Remove quotes from the String:

   `String inputJSON = "{'links':[],'format':'csv'}";`
2. Create a JSONArray from the String `'[]'`:

   `JSONArray jsonLinks = new JSONArray(jsonInput.getString("links"));`

Answer (score 3):

`'links':'[]'` this is not `JSONArray` . It should be something like `'links':[]`, without `''` quotes. Anything with `''` quotes basically behaves as a `String`.

For converting `links` to `JSONArray` you can try :-

`JSONArray links = new JSONArray((String)jsonInput.get("links"));`

Answer (score 2):

Your string isn't valid JSON. It should use double quotes to be. But even if it did, the "array" is quoted. So it is not an array, but a string.